# Loop sequence in OpenMP Collapse performance advise

Tags: openmp, xeon-phi

I found [Intel's performance suggestion on Xeon Phi](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/openmp-loop-collapse-directive) on `Collapse` clause in OpenMP.

> ```
> #pragma omp parallel for collapse(2) 
>   for (i = 0; i < imax; i++) { 
>     for (j = 0; j < jmax; j++) a[ j + jmax*i] = 1.; 
>   }
> ```
>
> Modified example for better performance:
>
> ```
> #pragma omp parallel for collapse(2) 
>   for (i = 0; i < imax; i++) { 
>      for (j = 0; j < jmax; j++) a[ k++] = 1.; 
>   }
> ```

<strike>I test both case in Fortran with similar code on regular CPU using GFortran 4.8, they both get correct result.</strike>  Test using similar Fortran Code with later code does not pass for GFortran5.2.0 and Intel 14.0

**But as far as I understand, the loop body for OpenMP should avoid "loop sequence dependent" variable, for this case is `k`, so why in the later case it can get correct result** and even better performance?

Comment: That's interesting. I'm surprised it works.  However, even if it does work I think this is a premature optimization. If the work that is being done is not much more significant than the cost to create iterators then your operation is likely memory bandwidth bound anyway. `a[ j + jmax*i] = 1.` is certainly memory bandwidth bound.

Comment: @Zboson Sorry, the test case I wrote in fortran has a bug at first. after fix it and choose some large imax, the later case always fail. and as Jim Cownie suggest, it might just a simple  bug.

Comment: Well at least you know now how to do it correctly. But I think it will be hard to benchmark this and show any difference. If `imax*jmax` is small then the time is dominated by the OpenMP overhead and if `imax*jmax` is large then it's memory bandwidth bound. If you don't read/write to memory then it would not be memory bandwidth bound.  You could do a reduction over `s += -1%k` or `s += -1%j` which adds alternating 1 and -1. The result is not interesting but it's does no reads or writes and GCC won't optimize it away like it would with `s++` so you could use it for benchmarking.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the equivalent code for the two approaches when using `collapse` clause. You could see the second one is better.

```
for(int k=0; k<imax*jmax; k++) {
  int i = k / jmax;
  int j = k % jmax;
  a[j + jmax*i]=1.;
}

for(int k=0; k<imax*jmax; k++) {
  a[k]=1.;
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised by Intel's example. I don't see why it should work. I would up vote you if you could answer this. Is this a new feature of OpenMP 4.0 or something?  I understand why it's more ideal based on your answer but that still does not explain how it works.

Comment: I skipped through the OpenMP 4.5 standard and I did not see anything explaining why this would work. I'm also skeptical of Intel's claim `AND the uses are complicated enough that they don't get dead-code-eliminated as part of compiler optimizations`. I don't see why this is too complicated for the compiler to optimize.

Comment: @Zboson I just tried on CPU. It does not work with `k++`. Could it be some specialization for MIC?

Comment: Which compiler did you use? Maybe this is a specialization of ICC?

Comment: Looks like a simple bug in the advice. It introduces a race on k and you shouldn't write that code! I'll try to get it fixed.

Comment: @Zboson I use ICC. I think the original advice might just try to show some concept.

Comment: Well, it looks like it's just poorly written advice. Your answer would have been better.